# LibJitsi Error with MediaDevice configuration

Tags: java, media, audio-streaming, jitsi

I am trying to build a Libjitsi audio-conferencing component for integration in a larger applet, starting from org.jitsi.examples.AVReceive2 and *.AVTransmit2 as templates. I have those examples up and running properly on one computer, but on every other computer I’ve tried, I keep getting an error message while initializing the MediaDevices. Here is the relevant code snippet for AVReceive2:

```
private final int localPortBase;
private MediaStream[] mediaStreams;
private final InetAddress remoteAddr;
private final int remotePortBase;

public AudioTranceiver(int localPortBase, String remoteHost, int remotePortBase) {

    this.localPortBase = localPortBase;
    this.remoteAddr = InetAddress.getByName(remoteHost);
    this.remotePortBase = remotePortBase;
}

public String start() {
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.AUDIO;
    MediaService mediaService = LibJitsi.getMediaService();
    int localPort = localPortBase;
    int remotePort = remotePortBase;

    mediaStreams = new MediaStream[1];
    for(MediaDevice audio : mediaService.getDevices(mediaType, MediaUseCase.ANY)) {
        System.out.println(audio.toString() + "\n");
    }
    try {
        MediaDevice device
            = mediaService.getDefaultDevice(mediaType, MediaUseCase.CALL);
        MediaStream mediaStream = mediaService.createMediaStream(device);

        mediaStream.setDirection(MediaDirection.RECVONLY);
......
......
```

This code generates a huge log. I've gone over it line-by-line both on "working" and "nonworking" systems, and haven't found any notable log discrepancies except for at the very end. On one computer, the one where the code works properly, the initialization concludes with the following:

```
Oct 29, 2015 3:08:53 PM org.jitsi.util.Logger info
INFO: Initializing audio devices
Oct 29, 2015 3:08:53 PM org.jitsi.util.Logger info
INFO: Initializing video devices
Oct 29, 2015 3:08:54 PM org.jitsi.util.Logger info
INFO: Support for the formats of camera 'Lenovo EasyCamera': [AVFRAME, class org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.codec.video.AVFrame, pixFmt 1, deviceSystemPixFmt 0x32595559]
Oct 29, 2015 3:08:54 PM org.jitsi.util.Logger info
INFO: Looking for configured audio devices.
Oct 29, 2015 3:08:54 PM org.jitsi.util.Logger info
INFO: Scanning for configured Video Devices.
Oct 29, 2015 3:08:54 PM org.jitsi.util.Logger info
INFO: Found Lenovo EasyCamera as a AVFRAME, class org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.codec.video.AVFrame video capture device.
Oct 29, 2015 3:08:56 PM org.jitsi.util.Logger info
INFO: GatherEntropy got: 88200 bytes
```

At this point, the computer will successfully receive an incoming RTP audio stream. On my other devices, I get an error and it crashes like the following:

```
Oct 29, 2015 2:58:12 PM org.jitsi.util.Logger info
INFO: Initializing audio devices
Oct 29, 2015 2:58:12 PM org.jitsi.util.Logger info
INFO: Initializing video devices
Oct 29, 2015 2:58:12 PM org.jitsi.util.Logger info


INFO: Looking for configured audio devices.
Oct 29, 2015 2:58:12 PM org.jitsi.util.Logger info
INFO: Scanning for configured Video Devices.
Oct 29, 2015 2:58:12 PM org.jitsi.util.Logger info
INFO: Found Desktop Streaming 0 as a AVFRAME, class org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.codec.video.AVFrame video capture device.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: direction
    at org.jitsi.service.neomedia.AbstractMediaStream.assertDirection(AbstractMediaStream.java:101)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.MediaStreamImpl.setDirection(MediaStreamImpl.java:2496)
    at org.jitsi.examples.AVReceive2.initialize(AVReceive2.java:131)
    at org.jitsi.examples.AVReceive2.main(AVReceive2.java:349)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've determined that the error is being thrown by the mediaStream.setDirection(MediaDirection.RECVONLY) call, and have tried to debug around that element.

Four points:

1. I modified the AVReceiver code to spit out a toString() of the MediaDevice right before the setDirection() call. On the working computer, I get:

Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio) : wasapi:{0.0.1.00000000}.{8941227a-5fac-4416-b31b-728eb2665a82
LINEAR, 48000.0 Hz, 16-bit, Mono, LittleEndian, Signed

LINEAR, 48000.0 Hz, 16-bit, Stereo, LittleEndian, Signed

LINEAR, 48000.0 Hz, 8-bit, Mono, Signed

LINEAR, 48000.0 Hz, 8-bit, Stereo, Signed

LINEAR, 22050.0 Hz, 16-bit, Mono, LittleEndian, Signed

LINEAR, 16000.0 Hz, 16-bit, Mono, LittleEndian, Signed

LINEAR, 11025.0 Hz, 16-bit, Mono, LittleEndian, Signed

LINEAR, 8000.0 Hz, 16-bit, Mono, LittleEndian, Signed

While on the nonworking device, I just get a generic toString() like:

Org.jits.impl.neomedia.device.AudioMediaDeviceImpl@131d2bf

I’m guessing this means that the MediaService isn’t locating or instantiating my device properly. I’ve expanded the search with a MediaService.getDevice(MediaType.AUDIO,MediaUseCase.ANY) to see if there are other devices and the service is just getting a bad default device, but the Impl class is the only device detected.

2. Before settling on Libjitsi, I did a few tours on the “working” computer through the JMF and FMJ precursors. It’s possible that I’ve got a configuration set up on my “working” computer that I don’t have on the other “nonworking” systems, but I can’t find it for the life of me.
3. I’ve made sure that the required native dll’s are properly placed in the classpath. Both systems are running the 32/64 bit dlls suitable for their architecture, and I'm getting no path or load errors. Definitely not the problem.
4. If I don't set the direction, I've determined that the device remains in the MediaDirection.INACTIVE state, which isn't an option.

I’ve been at this for days, trying to find a solution or to see if anyone else has had this problem, but no luck. Does anyone with Libjitsi experience have any idea what could be causing this??

Thanks a ton,

David